# OctoberCMS openssl_encrypt() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: octobercms

I installed the newest version of OctoberCMS using `composer create-project october/october` and everytime I login I get the following error:

```
openssl_encrypt() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given \
/home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php line 91
```

It's this part of the framework, which causes the error:

```
    $value = \openssl_encrypt(
        $serialize ? serialize($value) : $value,
        $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv
    );
```

No problems with version `437`, so I don't think it's a missing PHP module (OpenSSL support is compiled in in PHP). Does anyone have the same problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are an [open issue](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3681) on GitHub. Just downgrade Laravel version on composer.json file to 5.5.41, then do a `php artisan cache:clear` and delete your website cookies.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php namespace October\Rain\Cookie\Middleware;

use Config;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter as EncrypterContract;

class EncryptCookies extends \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies
{
    /**
     * Indicates if cookies should be serialized.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $serialize = true;

    public function __construct(EncrypterContract $encrypter)
    {
        parent::__construct($encrypter);
        $except = Config::get('cookie.unencryptedCookies', []);
        $this->disableFor($except);
    }
}
```

Replace vendor/october/rain/src/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php with code above